# Android listview onselect item has two values, how to get it separately

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which is populated by getting data from mysql db... the `ListView` contains three values from the database...

1. name
2. category
3. position

and I want to pass these values to the next `Activity`. So I used

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String items = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(mapping, CheckIn.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", items);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

But it produces an array {name = xxx , category = asdasd , position = ddxxddxx}

In the 2nd `Activity`, I want to get user comments about that specified name and insert it to another table. how to do so with the array?

the full code

```
try {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

            // prepare the HTTP GET call
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://hopscriber.com/place.php");
            // get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // get the response content as a string
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                // consume the entity
                entity.consumeContent();

                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the
                // connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all
                // system resources
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

                // return the JSON response
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_Name, object.getString("name"));
                        map.put(TAG_Category, object.getString("category"));

                        contactList.add(map);

                    }
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                        R.layout.menu_list_row, new String[] { TAG_Name,
                                TAG_Category }, new int[] { R.id.LR_Name,
                                R.id.LR_date });
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String items = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(mapping, CheckIn.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", items);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: extract required data from the array.

Comment: In this updated codings . Where do you placed my answer coding?

Comment: since it did not worked i replaced it with my old one

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (obj instanceof SQLiteCursor) {
                    SQLiteCursor Val = (SQLiteCursor) obj;
                    // this is storing to  textview
                    txtview.setText(cmnt.getString(0)); 
                    txtview.setText(cmnt.getString(1));
                    name = cmnt.getString(0);// this is store to string.
                    comments = cmnt.getString(1);
                }
            }
        });
```

### Intent passing:

```
  intent.putExtra("name",name);
  intent.putExtra("comments",comments);
```

### Get the values from second Activity:

```
  name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name", null);
  comments=getIntent().getStringExtra("comments", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LR_Name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LR_date)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckIn.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_Name, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_Category, cost);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

This worked for me... thank you for the support

Comment: Can you please add vote for me. I already sent answer is used for sqlite . So i has been post to u. Please support this.

Answer (score 0):

Recover the id and use in the second activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
        String rowid = String.valueOf(id)
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ID", rowid);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Retrieve in second activity using:

```
String rowid= getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
```

Don't forget to convert the id from string back to long and add 1 after you retrieve it in your second activity

Comment: But the NAME contails two vaules how to get it separately?

Comment: I apologize for missing that detail. have you considered using the id instead of the name? Since you are populating from a database table, your ListView will display them in the order they appear from the database (assuming you did not use ORDER BY in your query) therefore you should pass your ListView id to the second activity instead instead of the name. This way, in your second activity you retrieve the id, add 1 to it, and ask get the name at that id row in your database table. (I asked you to add 1 because the ListView index starts from 0 and your database table id starts from 1)

Answer (score -1):

From your 1st `Activity` just pass Name, category and position using bundle.
Something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SearchAssetActivity.this,
                        CheckInActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", xxx);
bundle.putString("sno", asasas);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in second `Activity` you can retrive like this in your `onCreate()`:

```
String name= getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

This way you can retrieve any number of parameters

Comment: Loshi wants to get the two columns values from listview selected positions. By your codings she can get only one values

Comment: @Venkatesh Oh then I guess your answer would suit her better than my approach. +1 for your answer. :)