# Listview retrieval in android

Tags: android, listview

In my application i am showing data form database in a list view.I have list view with 4 text views in column wise,if user clicks a particular row i have to get these 4 text view values. Please Help me.

Comment: you have only 4 rows in listview??

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516626/android-listview-onselect-item-has-two-values-how-to-get-it-separately/11517697#11517697> this link will helps you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String textview1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
            String textview2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
            String textview3 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3)).getText().toString();
            String textview4 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text4)).getText().toString();

         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is maintain four array lists 
create these by the database values you fetch 
and on list item click 
get the value of each individual item like

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String  s1 = ArrayList1.get(position);

    String  s2 = ArrayList2.get(position);

     String s3 = ArrayList3.get(iposition);

    String  s4 = ArrayList4.get(position);





    }
});
```